# Selenium will open chrome tab but not find URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium starts a blank chrome tab but does not go to the specified link. I would Imagine its a fairly simple fix. My selenium is up to date.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc84u.png)

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7UKm.png)

Comment: try giving https://www.google.com

Comment: Do not post code and errors as images.

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow. A quick tip for beginners: please put your code and the error output not as a screenshot, and even worst, not as a link to those files. You'll ease the live of the answerer and enhance the possibility of getting your question answered by doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below command

`browser.get('https://www.google.com')`